# ASP.NET Protecting Pictures Directory from Anonymous Users

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm sorry, I know very similar questions have been asked and answered, but I cannot protect a directory of pictures of my infant son from anonymous users.

I have tried placing a web.config directly in the pictures directory:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have also tried using a location tag in the base web.config but that also does not appear to work.

Either way I can still access /pics/ApplePicking.jpg when I run my project locally.  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

As a new user of IIS, I didnt realize that I had to add a handler to the server configuration to make it 'see' jpg's in order to enforce the setting in the web.config.

If anyone else comes across this question, placing a web.config file in the directory you wish to protect does work, but you also need to add a 'Handler Mapping' for the file types you are trying to protect otherwise IIS will just serve it as a normal resource without enforcing the authorization.